# Image of linear operator not closed

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Just wanted my work checked - to show that the image of a linear operator is not necessarily closed.

Let $T:\ell ^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \ell ^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the identity map. Let $x_1=(1,0,0,...), x_2=(1,\frac{1}{2},0,...), x_3=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},0,...),... $ be a sequence in $\ell ^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $x=(1,1,1,...)$. Then $x_n\rightarrow x$ and so $T(x_n)\rightarrow T(x) $ but $T(x)\notin \text{Im}(T) $. So the range of $T$ is not closed.

Is this ok?

CORRECTION: I mean $x=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...)$.

Comment: It is not true that $x_n \to x$, and your conclusion that $T(x) \notin \operatorname{Im}(T)$ is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Your work is incorrect.

**Hint:** The image of the identity map is $\ell^2(\Bbb R)$, which is certainly a closed subset of itself. Instead, consider the map $T$ defined by
$$
T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\dots) = (\xi_1,\xi_2/2,\xi_3/3, \dots).
$$

Comment: I've made a correction. So if instead we define $T$ as above but from the subspace of $\ell ^2 (\mathbb{R})$ which has only finitely many non zero elements.

Comment: @Anon I don't understand why you insist on using the identity map. Yes, if you define $T$ to be the inclusion map from the space of "finite" sequences to $\ell^2$, then $T$ does not have a closed image.

Comment: I just tried to complete an exercise I was given independently and just wanted to know if my own ideas actually were right.

Comment: @Anon You had the right general idea. The key is that the image of a linear operator is a subspace, so ultimately the image needs to be an example of a non-closed subspace of a normed space. The "finite" sequences form such a subspace.